# Certificates failed to load in Azure ML retraining via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

During the retraining process of Azure ML Predictive Model following the guidelines on Microsoft Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/retrain-existing-resource-manager-based-web-service 
I reached the final step with updating the existing Predictive Experiment via PowerShell, but the error occurs:

```
    Update-AzureRmMlWebService : 
Request Id: 2d3bd8db-44fb-42f3-aeb3-907ba8a13698
Error Code: InternalServerError
Error Message: An internal server error occurred. Please try again. If the problem persists, report it on the Azure Machine Learning 
forums.
Error Target: 
Error Details:
    [Code=FailedToLoadCertificate, Message=The certificate with the following thumbprint: 19C7A723C863C127ADC5A71894FF1814329C0C55 
failed to load]
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-AzureRmMlWebService -Name Finalexperiment -ResourceGroupName ' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Update-AzureRmMlWebService], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Resource Provider Error,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.MachineLearning.UpdateAzureMLWebService
```

Does anyone know how to load those certificates?